# Python: How to get values and not object type while iterating through pandas Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, literate-programming

I am trying to fetch values of each row of pandas dataframe using below code.

```
points = [ makePoint(row) for row in df.iterrows() ]
```

here df has 4 column. each contains integer data.

while i try to print row, it returns follow,

```
1    3
2    3
3    4
4    5
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

I just need

```
[3,3,4,5]
```

and don't want index, name and dtype.

Comment: Can you add sample data, 3-4 rows and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Use `tolist()` if need convert `Series` to `list` and [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) return tuples - index with `Series`, so add `i` for unpacking it:

```
points = [ makePoint(row).tolist() for i, row in df.iterrows() ]
```

Or `list`:

```
points = [ list(makePoint(row)) for i, row in df.iterrows() ]
```

Another solution:

```
points = df.apply(makePoint, axis=1).values.tolist()
```

Comment: But this will result in a list of lists afaik.

Comment: Yes, it depends what OP need, so I add comment under question.